# Create trigger for adding new users to wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need to add a users full name to the buddy press extended profile field every time a new user is created. This is normal functionality, but we are syncing users from Active Directory and when that ran users names are not being populated. I have created a SQL query that works for combining first and last name and updating it to where i need. My issue comes when trying to create a trigger in phpMyAdmin.

This is the error i receive:

The following query has failed:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update users` 
AFTER UPDATE ON `wp_bp_xprofile_data` 
FOR EACH ROW 
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE user_data AS 
 SELECT u.user_id
   , (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id = u.user_id AND meta_key = 'first_name' LIMIT 1) AS first_name
  , (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id = u.user_id AND meta_key = 'last_name' LIMIT 1) AS last_name
  , (SELECT `value` FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data WHERE user_id = u.user_id AND field_id = '1' LIMIT 1) AS bp_name
  , (SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name)) AS full_name 
  FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data u ; 
  UPDATE wp_bp_xprofile_data u JOIN user_data b ON u.user_id=b.user_id 
  SET u.value=b.full_name;"
```

MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE wp_bp_xprofile_data u JOIN user_data b ON u.user_id=b.user_id ' at line 12

Here is the code i used.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE user_data AS
  SELECT
  u.user_id,
  (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id = u.user_id AND meta_key = 'first_name' LIMIT 1) AS first_name,
  (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id = u.user_id AND meta_key = 'last_name' LIMIT 1) AS last_name,
  (SELECT `value` FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data WHERE user_id = u.user_id AND field_id = '1' LIMIT 1) AS bp_name,
  (SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name)) AS full_name
FROM
  wp_bp_xprofile_data u
 ;

UPDATE wp_bp_xprofile_data u
  JOIN user_data b
    ON u.user_id=b.user_id 
  SET u.value=b.full_name;
```

[Trigger Inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHHkI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't entered a BRGIN or ENd

Try

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER `update users` 
AFTER UPDATE ON `wp_bp_xprofile_data` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE user_data AS 
 SELECT u.user_id
   , (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id = u.user_id AND meta_key = 'first_name' LIMIT 1) AS first_name
  , (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id = u.user_id AND meta_key = 'last_name' LIMIT 1) AS last_name
  , (SELECT `value` FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data WHERE user_id = u.user_id AND field_id = '1' LIMIT 1) AS bp_name
  , (SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name)) AS full_name 
  FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data u ; 
  UPDATE wp_bp_xprofile_data u JOIN user_data b ON u.user_id=b.user_id 
  SET u.value=b.full_name;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

But i am not sure that trigger will even work, it only removes the syntax errors.

As far as i know, you can't update the table that invoked the Trigger, because your update would also invoke a new trigger and so on.